# Putting a cell into edit mode from a Popup menu

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm struggling to make a JTable's cells go directly into edit mode via a Popup menu (shown by right clicking a cell). Any info I've found talks about how to change the number of clicks required, rather than by selecting a JMenu item.

Hopefully this code is useful in understanding what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class CellTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();     
        p.add(new CustomTable());

        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class CustomTable extends JTable implements ActionListener{
    JPopupMenu popup;
    JMenuItem unlock;

    public CustomTable(){
        setModel(new CustomTableModel());
        popup = new JPopupMenu();
        unlock = new JMenuItem("Unlock");
        unlock.addActionListener(this);
        popup.add(unlock);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){maybeShowPopup(e);}
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){maybeShowPopup(e);}
        });
    }

    private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e){
        int row = getSelectedRow();
        if(row >= 0 && row < getRowCount())
            setRowSelectionInterval(row,row);
        else
            clearSelection();
        if(row < 0) return;
        if(e.isPopupTrigger() && e.getComponent() instanceof JTable){
           popup.show(e.getComponent(),e.getX(),e.getY());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Code to put the cell into edit mode?");
    }

}

class CustomTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    String[][] data = {{"Nick","25","Swindon"},{"Will","47","Coventry"},    {"Jane","28","Reading"}};
    @Override
    public int getRowCount(){
        return data[0].length;
    }
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount(){
        return 3;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col){
        return data[row][col];
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You were asked in you last question to post a proper [mcve]. I suggested how to create the `MCVE`. The essence of your question is how to place a cell in edit mode on a user event. There is no need for a custom TableModel or JTable or a popup menu to test the basic concept. All you need is  JFrame with a JTable with a DefaultTableModel and a JButton.and  a simple ActionLIstener for the button.  For the code in the ActionListener  you look at the JTable API. There are methods to get the selected row/column and a method to place a cell in edit mode.

Comment: sorry - I thought that was the minimum code required to describe the problem: I misread your last answer and thought i did need the TableModel. I'll have a look for the method to place the cell in edit mode. thank you.